# How to set selectable day on DatePicker to 3 days from now on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

**How to set the date picker only can be select on future day - 3 or 10 days on flutter?**

i only found solution for selectable days on workdays..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can select dates after 3 days only. you can edit value to make it after 10 days.

Code:

```
var result = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)),
                firstDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)),
                lastDate: DateTime(2020),
              );
```

Today is 15, Feb

[image]